# Object reference not set to instance of an object when passing object to new window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a subwindow that is supposed to get a string when initialized.
The main window has this code:

```
 CountryView cv = new CountryView(item.Country);
 cv.Show();
```

item.Country being a string. While the subwindow has:

```
public partial class CountryView : Window
{
    public CountryView(string thisCountry)
    {
        lblCountryName.Content = $"{thisCountry}";
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Label code:

```
 <Label x:Name="lblCountryName" Content="" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

It keeps saying object reference not set to instance of an object. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullReferenceException` occurs when you try to access a member of an object that is currently null. In your case, this error is occurring because you're trying to access `lblCountryName` before the `InitializeComponent()` method is called, which initializes the elements in your XAML and assigns values to the automatically generated fields in the code behind class.

You should write:

```
public partial class CountryView : Window
{
    public CountryView(string thisCountry)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // Initialize the window components first
        lblCountryName.Content = thisCountry; // Set the content after initialization
    }
}
```